# Unknown Function takes 100% CPU time

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

One page in my ASP.NET WebForms start unexpectedly load very slow (~20 secs, just one page, others are ~4 secs).

After Collecting CPU usage data, I can see some **Unknown function** is using 100% of CPU time.
Methods which are called in my Page_Load (on affected page) takes around only 5% of CPU time, Site.Master is around 1%

Could anyone suggest how can I troubleshoot this? How can I find cause of this?

[Unknown function - picture from CPU usage data Collector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ72V.png)

Comment: You need dump analysis https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool#data-analysis